# Tiff raster display with polygon layer

Tags: qgis, polygon, geotiff-tiff, layers

Does any body have an idea about why *.tiff images are not displayed when added as raster layer to QGIS after adding a vector layer which has a polygon geometry?

SOLVED !!
In fact the tiff is displayed but not show in the canvas due to a mislocation.
a "(QgisInterface)->zoomToActiveLayer()" after adding the raster layer should bring the image to display ^^
Thanks everybody !

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: I'm using Qgis !

Comment: Does the raster not display at all or just not in the correct location?

Comment: The raster layer is added.. but the image is not displayed !

Comment: Are you certain that it's not displayed? Have you looked around? Often I find that rasters don't have any spatial reference so they sometimes don't line up where they're supposed to. That could be your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

In fact the tiff is displayed but not show in the canvas due to a mislocation.

a "(QgisInterface)->zoomToActiveLayer()" after addig the raster layer should bring the image to display ^^

Thanks everybody